# How to Extend IOS SimpleURLConnections HTTP POST to Send Description Decodable by CGI Perl

Tags: ios, perl, http-headers, cgi, multipartform-data

I would like to extend the sample ios code called SimpleURLConnections. This sample code can upload a file using HTTP POST. I have enabled my apache web server with a cgi script written in Perl to receive the HTTP POST that addresses the cgi script and successfully uploads the file. The extension I would like to make is to add a title or description of the uploaded file. I have tried to update the multipart form data in the sample code and a corresponding change to my cgi script to transfer this description, but it is failing. The cgi script cannot read in the description using the cgi.pm method called param(). I'm hoping someone can help. Here are the details:

The multipart form data BEFORE my modification looks like the following (NOTE: the SimpleURLConnections routine inserts the image file between the Content-Type and the 2nd boundary on the fly):

```
--Boundary-D4AFFBA9-AD92-4697-9184-7BDA128C3B97
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="fileContents"; filename="1234567/TestImage1.png"
Content-Type: image/png

--Boundary-D4AFFBA9-AD92-4697-9184-7BDA128C3B97
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="uploadButton"

Upload File
--Boundary-D4AFFBA9-AD92-4697-9184-7BDA128C3B97--
```

The multipart form data AFTER my modification looks like the following:

```
--Boundary-D4AFFBA9-AD92-4697-9184-7BDA128C3B97
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Title"; title="Hello World"
Content-Type: text/plain
--Boundary-D4AFFBA9-AD92-4697-9184-7BDA128C3B97
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="fileContents"; filename="1234567/TestImage1.png"
Content-Type: image/png


--Boundary-D4AFFBA9-AD92-4697-9184-7BDA128C3B97
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="titleButton"
my Title

--Boundary-D4AFFBA9-AD92-4697-9184-7BDA128C3B97
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="uploadButton"

Upload File
--Boundary-D4AFFBA9-AD92-4697-9184-7BDA128C3B97--
```

My cgi script looks like the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -wT
use strict;use CGI;
use CGI::Carp qw ( fatalsToBrowser );
use File::Basename;

my $upload_dir = "/Library/WebServer/Documents/upload";

my $query = new CGI;

my $title = $query->param("Title");

#if (!$title) {
#    die "the title is $title. $!";
#}

if ( !$filename ) {
        print $query->header ( );
        die "There was a problem uploading your photo (try a smaller file). : $!";
        exit;
}
...

open ( UPLOADFILE, ">$upload_dir/$filename" ) or die "$!";
while ( <$upload_filehandle> ) {
    print UPLOADFILE;
}

close UPLOADFILE;
```

This code works fine and the uploaded file gets written to the upload_dir.

But, if I uncomment that little block of code:

```
if (!$title) {
    die "the title is $title. $!";
}
```

the script dies with an error that indicates that $title has no value:

```
[Tue Sep 27 17:09:17 2011] [error] [client 10.0.1.2] [Tue Sep 27 17:09:17 2011] upload.cgi: Use of uninitialized value $title in print at /Library/WebServer/CGI-Executables/upload.cgi line 79.
```

So, is the problem with my multipart form data, the cgi script, or is it not possible to pass this data in the multipart form data? Is there an alternate way?

Thanks

Ok, after getting help from @AFresh1, I found the problem. The problem was in the details of how the multipart form data was created. First I will show the wrong way.

```
NSString *title = @"Hello World";
bodySuffixStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:     // create the footer for the POST message
            @
            "\r\n"
            "--%@\r\n"
            "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"titleButton\"\r\n"
            "%@\r\n\r\n"
            "--%@\r\n"
            "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploadButton\"\r\n"
            "\r\n"
            "Upload File\r\n"
            "--%@--\r\n" 
            "\r\n",
            boundaryStr,
            title,
            boundaryStr, 
            boundaryStr
        ];
```

Now the correct way (a very subtle change in the 7th line - moved the CR/LF):

```
NSString *title = @"Hello World";
bodySuffixStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:     // create the footer for the POST message
            @
            "\r\n"
            "--%@\r\n"
            "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"titleButton\"\r\n"
            "\r\n%@\r\n"
            "--%@\r\n"
            "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploadButton\"\r\n"
            "\r\n"
            "Upload File\r\n"
            "--%@--\r\n" 
            "\r\n",
            boundaryStr,
            title,
            boundaryStr, 
            boundaryStr
        ];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the content goes in the space after the header
and before the next boundary not in a title attribute.  The part header being everything after the boundary and before the blank line.

If you are want to get "Hello World" into $title using `$query->param('Title')` I think you will need something more like this (note that Content-type defaults to text/plain):

```
--Boundary-D4AFFBA9-AD92-4697-9184-7BDA128C3B97
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Title"

Hello World
--Boundary-D4AFFBA9-AD92-4697-9184-7BDA128C3B97
```

Comment: no, sorry. If I understood the change you suggested correctly, that does not seem to work.

Comment: I believe it should work, in my testing it does. Can you try with the original working code (without your additions) and see if you can get the value of `$query->('titleButton')`?

Comment: Ok, so I misunderstood where you were suggesting the change should be. I have made the change, but it is still not working (although the error is slightly different. First, just to be clear, here is the changed multipart form data:

Comment: --Boundary-CD342BC3-E13C-4CEA-A896-3CC9F04283FE
    Content-Disposition: form-data; name="fileContents"; filename="1234567/TestImage1.png"
    Content-Type: image/png


    --Boundary-CD342BC3-E13C-4CEA-A896-3CC9F04283FE
    Content-Disposition: form-data; name="titleButton"
    Hello World

    --Boundary-CD342BC3-E13C-4CEA-A896-3CC9F04283FE
    Content-Disposition: form-data; name="uploadButton"

    Upload File
    --Boundary-CD342BC3-E13C-4CEA-A896-3CC9F04283FE--

Comment: The error used to be a 2 line error. The first line at the web server error log said "Use of uninitialized value $title in concatenation (.) or string". The second line used to say "the title is . ". That second line is my "die" statement resulting from $title not having a value. The new error only contains my "die" error. It says "the title is . 0".  That "0" is the error message passed from the system (which is not very helpful). But the system doesn't think the $title is uninitialized, but my script doesn't think there is a value there. Any further thoughts?

Comment: The new form-data is hard to read in the comment but I don't see a part with the name "Title".  However, `0` is a value (and not uninitialized), it just evaluates to false. I agree it is not  what you want. Does this new error come when you are trying to get the value of titleButton?

Comment: Based on your earlier comment, it looked like you were suggesting that I should be putting my title "Hello World" after the Content-Disposition that contained the name="titleButton". I came to that conclusion because your comment said query->('titleButton'). Is that correct? To answer your question, the error comes as a result of my cgi script trying to set the value of $title. Specifically, the script says: my $title = $query->param("titleButton"); if (! $title) { die "the title is $title. $!"; }

Comment: It should not matter where you put it as long as the multipart form-data is formatted properly.  However, since you moved "Hello World" into the part with the name attribute of titleButton you need to `$title = $query->param('titleButton')` but that was just to make sure you could get any useful data out of the submitted form.

Comment: ok, but as you can see from the previous comment, that how my script is written. Notice that the text "Hello World" is on a line of its own. Is that correct? Here is the form data again (wish I could make this look pretty): 'Boundary...' 'Content-Disposition...filename=...' 'Content-Type...' '<INSERTED FILE>'  '--Boundary...' 'Content-Disposition...name="titleButton' 'Hello World'  '--Boundary...' 'Content-Disposition...name="uploadButton" 'Upload File'  '--Boundary...'

Comment: Not sure how I missed that, but does it really say "the title is $title.$!"? That would explain more why it outputs 0, because there wasn't likely an error that would set $!. That doesn't really explain why it won't get the form data.  Perhaps try `use Data::Dumper` and then `die Dumper $query` right after `my $query = new CGI;` to see what is in the object?

Comment: good tip on dumper. Not sure what the dump means though. The title is in the dump. Here is what I think is relevant:                         '.parameters' => [                                                                           'fileContents',                                                                          'titleButton'                                                        ],

Comment: followed by 'titleButton' => ['Hello World'], 'fileContents' => [$VAR1->{'.tmpfiles'}{'*Fh::fh000011234567/TestImage1.png'}{'hndl'}].

Comment: Actually, what I just showed you from the dump is actually working. Prior to running that dump, I changed the way I created the multipart form data. I moved the CR/LF that preceded the 'Hello World'. I will create an answer so I can show the change. Thanks for the tips